# DISTINCT ON with wrong output

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

```
3   2014-09-30 16:07:18.690498
2   2014-09-30 16:06:30.224745
1   2014-09-30 16:04:45.844215
```

---

```
select DISTINCT ON (DATE(dt))
       id, dt
       from test
       ORDER BY DATE(dt) DESC
```

The output is the id 2, and should be the id 3.

What I am doing wrong? I am only interest in this type of query with `DISTINCT ON`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
select DISTINCT ON (DATE(dt))
       id, dt
       from test
       ORDER BY DATE(dt) DESC, dt DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to add order by `dt` to get consistent result:

```
select distinct on (date(dt))
    id, dt
from test
order by date(dt) desc, dt desc
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cb890/4)</kbd>**